# Redirect node type to a view

Tags: 7, rules, uri

I have created a view that lists all the nodes of a certain type. If you go to view the node on it's own page I would like it to forward to my view. I tried doing this using rules but as I display the full nodes in my view it created a loop. I could give all my nodes a /nodetype/title path if I can set up some wildcard redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function MYMODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'load' &&
      $node->type == 'your_type' &&
      $_GET['q'] == '/node/' . $node->nid) {
    drupal_goto("/", NULL, NULL, 301);
    exit;
  }
}
```

It has the advantage of not using `hook_init()` and working regardless of custom url aliases.

Comment: What do you see as a disadvantage of using `hook_init()`?  It is essentially the second(?) hook called for all page requests.

Comment: @MPD generally I like to keep anything I can out of `hook_init()` as it's always called for bootstrap (imagecache generation, ajax handler, 404, etc.). I don't think it's important enough in this instance to merit much thought to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pathauto setting, such as, "the-base-from-the-auto-setting/[nid]", and all of these nodes use the automatic alias and not a custom alias, you can implement [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6) in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_init () {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri());

  if (strpos($path, "/the-base-from-the-auto-setting/") !== false) {
    drupal_goto("/the-path-of-the-view/", NULL, NULL, 301);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Note that [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6) calls exit on its own, but I keep the `exit` there as a reminder.

The above is untested, but modified from a code snippet that I frequently use that does a [drupal_not_found()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_not_found/6).  See http://drupal.org/node/846930#comment-3451328 for more details.

Comment: doesn't `request_uri()` return the aliased path already? (I made the same mistake in my first answer:)

Comment: `request_uri()` returns the path that the page was requested as.  This covers the condition when aliases are enabled, but global redirect is disabled.

Comment: I'm with you now, didn't get it before. I copied from your example for mine and incorrectly used `request_uri()` to get the unaliased path and wrongly assumed you'd done the same. Sorry!