# Display node through panels but limit/deny access directly

Tags: 6, panels, users

I have a panel that displays a webform node depending on the fulfillment of certain selection rules (visibility rules) within the panel.  However, I want to be able to prevent access to the webform directly.  I have tried to unpublish the node, but this affects the display in the panel as well.

Edit: I'd also like to avoid adding code into template files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

> Edit: I'd also like to avoid adding code into template files etc.

do you mean that you want a existing module / UI only solution?  If so, I can't help you with that.

If you don't mind doing a small custom module, this is a somewhat common task that has been answered a few times on this site, and the main SO site, under slightly different titles.

Essentially, you want to redirect a node page to another page or you want to not have a node every viewable on its own.

Two questions worth reading are

[Redirect node type to a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/redirect-node-type-to-a-view/3491#3491)

[How to prevent access to Views-only content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/how-to-prevent-access-to-views-only-content/5651#5651)

Those two solutions can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't mind doing custom modules at all, although I would prefer a UI option if possible.  The comment was simply to avoid answers that meant adding code into .tpl files or template.php.